# Theorems or results one can use to prove properties of integrands

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Consider a function $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $(t,x)\mapsto f(t,x)$ for which we do not know much about its regularity in $x$. Define now
$$(t,x) \mapsto g(t,x):= \int_a^t f(s,x)ds, \quad t\in [a,b], \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Imagine we now know much more about $g$, for instance, $g(t,\cdot)$ is $C^1$ for all $t\in [a,b]$ or whatever property we know about $g$ on $x\in \mathbb R$.

My question is: what results or theorems transfer such knowledge on $g$ to $f$? That is, under what conditions can $f$ inherit the same properties of $g$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: hi, the bounty expires in 7 hours if you could check recent answers, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I guess there is nothing much to say about f. Even though proving it is not easy, take the example of $f(t, x) = 1_\mathbb{Q}(t+x)$. This leads to $g = 0$ but f is pretty hectic.

Note : $1_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $0$ otherwise

Comment: So then the only solution is to study $f$ directly ignoring whatever properties one has on $g$? :(

Comment: What about imposing that $f$ is continuous in $t$? Does that still not help?

Comment: @Martingalo are you asking that because this is part of a "bigger problem" ?

Comment: It is indeed, but I am just guessing, because it feels elementary and I guess it is studied somewhere, don't you think?